# Data gridview spliting one column to multiple column

Tags: c#

I have been using a datagridview in my application.

I have add below columns in it

```
 dataGridView1.Columns["Name"].HeaderText ="Name"

 dataGridView1.Columns["Age"].HeaderText = "Age"

 dataGridView1.Columns["Gender"].HeaderText ="Gender"
```

Now i need to add Firstname middlename and last name under "Name" column of datagridview.

Previously my data grid looks like

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7lyC.png)

But now i want the grid to display

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcJIP.png)

But i cant able to add it.

Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: There isn's `datagridview` controller in `MVC`

Comment: sorry can you please help me out in splitting of one column in datagridview

Comment: your question is not very clear. can you draw and attach a little sample?

Comment: row["Name"] = human.Firstname + " " + human.Middlename + " " + human.Lastname

Comment: Leszek Repie thanks for your reply but i am binding my source to datagridview

Comment: There is a very nice example and also code on this page. Please review, Link https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16049/Merge-Header-GridView-DataGrid